# import not working in python with multiple directory

Tags: python, python-module

```
Project_folder
    main.py
    folder_x
        __init__.py
        A.py
        B.py
    folder_y
        __init__.py
        C.py
        D.py
```

I have a project structure like the above. In `main.py`, I am importing `A.py`

```
from folder_x.A import A
```

And in `A.py` file I have

```
from B import B
```

But it's giving

```
    from B import B
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'B'
```

I have found some answers (Updating sys path) to some related questions. But is there any other way?
And I am not also allowed to modify `A.py` or `B.py`

Comment: change `from B import B` to `from .B import B`

Comment: I am not allowed to change file ```A.py``` or ```B.py``` @Gahan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python Interpreter does not interpret your code in the way you are trying to assume.

whenever you check - `print(sys.path)` all the paths which are listed are available to use import statement for python, and it must be used to import in proper hierarchy in order for you to perform operation successfully.

Since you are executing project, your root working directory would be: `Project_folder`

`from folder_x.A import A` will work since path can be mapped from `Project_folder`

in order for you to be able to use modules internally you need to use modules internal imports with relative path to `Project_folder`

i.e. `from folder_x.B import B` and `from folder_x.A import A`

Since you are mentioning that you are not allowed to change `A.py` or `B.py`

only two possibilities you have:

1. Move the file itself under `Project_folder`
2. use `sys.path.insert` or `sys.path.append` to add your folder path `folder_x` to the system path.

Answer (score 1):

When you are executing the main.py python interpreter use that main.py file path as a base path for executing your whole application.

That base path referred to the import module in your application throughout.
So, whenever you do import please confirm that your import should follow that base path (as mentioned above) directory structure.

Following are the solution you can try,
Just adding the above lines in your code will help you to resolve issues in a better way.

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.pardir)))
```

or

```
import sys
from os.path import dirname, abspath
d=dirname(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `B.py` from folder_x to Project_folder

Comment: Not allowed to modify ```A.py``` or ```B.py```

Answer (score 0):

You need to try this

```
from folder_x.B import B
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sys
function_path = r'C:\Users\hogsione\jupyter' # Folder path where your .py file is present
sys.path.insert(1, function_path)
from A import my_function
```